# Вложенный запрос laravel

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel

Никак не могу понять как в laravel сделать вложенный запрос из своего:

```
SELECT date, 
    (SELECT name_disc 
            from disciplines 
            WHERE code_discipline = code_disc group by code_disc) as CP,
point, rating, code_discipline  FROM exams_info WHERE student = $student 
ORDER BY date
```

Может кто-нибудь помочь советом как это сделать используя Database: Query Builder?

Comment: Вам нужен `JOIN` запрос, а не селект в селекте. В ларавеле они тоже реализованы, насколько я знаю.

Comment: @RAMe0 Спасибо! А как сделать вложенный запрос или лучше их не использовать?

Comment: да вложенные запросы не самая лучшая идея. Query Builder'ом вы вложенные запросы не сделаете. Посмотрите в сторону связей.